# Ansible aws_ec2 plugin how to set credentials for discovered hosts?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

Need to launch ad-hook commands like "-m ping" on existing ec2 instances, but it requred key-pair.

How to set key-pair for boto, like "aws_access_key_id" stored in  ~/.aws/credentials ?

Also, have a problem invertory:
i got "invertory" folder near Ansible, where stored both local hosts and aws_ec2.yml file. But ansible-invertory --list works only for aws_ec2.yml file...

Answer (score 0):

You can declare appropriate credentials and other host-sensitive variable right in the `inventory` file.

I.e.:

```
[ec2fleet]
35.... ansible_ssh_user=ec2-user
15.... ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
[ec2fleet:vars]
ansible_user=deployer
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/deployer/.ssh/deployer.pem
```